# Can we use RUN instruction with base image as scratch?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

FROM scratch

RUN mkdir hello

This is my Dockerfile, and i am unable to build image for this.

Build command is  **docker build -t sample .**

Below is the output

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB

Step 1/2 : FROM scratch

--->

Step 2/2 : RUN mkdir hello

---> Running in faafa9f9aa98

OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: Any logs after docker build . ?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the exact commands you used to build and the build logs.

Comment: I want to use RUN instruction with base image as scratch
And don't know which kernel it will take for building image.

Comment: containers run in the same kernel as the OS in which the are run.

Answer (score 2):

A scratch image contains nothing, not even `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/mkdir`.

So you can't `RUN` anything unless you `COPY` in into the image first.